# 10 year anniversary

Tags: discussion

I've been notified that the site is very close to its 10 year anniversary.  Woo hoo!

Stack Exchange has contacted us to indicate they are interested to highlight this accomplishment, in a blog post (similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/08/19/celebrating-the-stack-exchange-sites-that-turned-10-years-old/)).

Would you all like to see our site listed in that blog post?  Can anyone suggest a brief description of the site, along the lines shown in the linked blog post?  We've been given the following guidance:

> When working on the story, imagine that your community was a person who was invited to a conference to speak. The organisers asked this person for some fun facts and a short bio. Think about what this person would write and send us this story. Keep in mind that we may need to shorten any submissions that are too lengthy. We don't want to turn the blog post into too long of an article.

We also have the opportunity to suggest a meta post that they'll link to, in their blog post.

Also, would you like Stack Exchange to add a temporary "10 year Anniversary" banner to the site?  The banner would be live for one month. If there is a meta post on the site that you think the banner should link to, please indicate that as well.

Comment: I support all of these suggestions.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, I think we should write something for the blog post. My suggestion is the following:

> What is left of Computer Science when we remove programming? More than just a bit! Algorithm design and analysis, formal systems, distributed computing, computational geometry, cryptography, and more. Students, researchers, programmers, teachers have all asked us questions when they need a bit more science to solve their computer problems.

Also, I notice the blog lists "interesting questions". I'm not sure who decides what questions those are, but I have a few candidates, in no particular order:

- [What is the definition of P, NP, NP-complete and NP-hard?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/9556/what-is-the-definition-of-p-np-np-complete-and-np-hard) I usually refer people to this post for a quick introduction to the P vs. NP problem.
- [How to fool the "try some test cases" heuristic: Algorithms that appear correct, but are actually incorrect](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/29475/how-to-fool-the-try-some-test-cases-heuristic-algorithms-that-appear-correct) This was a good question with many nice answers, but the tricky [2D local maximum finding algorithm](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/90038/65339) is the highlight for me.
- [Is there any data structure that can't be represented or described inside a computer?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/87496/is-there-any-data-structure-that-cant-be-represented-or-described-inside-a-comp) I like this somewhat naive question because it illustrates that for many problems in CS, asking the right question may be the hardest part of the problem. Andrej's answer is also excellent.
- [Why is writing down mathematical proofs more fault-proof than writing computer code?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/85327/why-is-writing-down-mathematical-proofs-more-fault-proof-than-writing-computer-c) A bit more philosophical than other questions, but one that has attracted some good answers (and a lot bad ones too, fortunately, we have voting)
- [Minimum number of shopping trips for a group of people to buy presents for each other](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/69615/minimum-number-of-shopping-trips-for-a-group-of-people-to-buy-presents-for-each) I had a few fun weeks looking for the answer to this one in between attending lectures.

I have no real opinion on the banner, but why not.

Comment: Nice blurb, we can use that one!

Comment: I don't think we should use "reference questions" in that list as they are crutches for us to have linkable replacements of textbook chapters. They are not what we would want to advertise with, IMHO.

Comment: I'm sure everybody has their favorite questions -- I warmly remember our series on heap automata, and the stick-cutting question that led to a research paper -- but I'm not sure how we would select the "best" ones. Votes are only our measure, and they are skewed. ‎

Comment: Yes, it is not that easy to find the best questions. Perhaps we should simply grab a list of candidates and ask the CM's which one they think would appeal to the audience of the blog post.

Comment: @Discretelizard I'd love to look at your final list but honestly, you all know your site better than I. The purpose of the blog is to showcase the top questions you feel are reflective of what's on topic or interesting here. You'd all be the better judge!